# Very low accuracy and high loss with LSTM model

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, robotics

I try to learn the inverse kinematics of a robotic manipulator. To do that I have a simulator with which I acquired data.

My dataset is composed of positions in X, Y and Z and actuator variables (6 of them). That represents around 310 000 rows. Therefore, the inputs of my NN are the positions (3 inputs) and the outputs the actuator variables (6 outputs). Just before (when my dataset were much simpler, 3 outputs only) I managed to obtain good results with a MLP. However, now that the dataset is much more complicated, I did not manage to obtain a similar result.

I decided to explore a bit the option of RNN and particularly the LSTM. However, I still have some difficulties to obtain convenient results. In fact, at this moment I only achieve 0.17 of accuracy and 0.06 loss (a good value of loss would be 0.0001).

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Chargement des données
data = np.genfromtxt('/dataprocess.csv', delimiter=',')
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data[1:,[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]] = scaler.fit_transform(data[1:,[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]])

# Diviser les données en ensembles d'entraînement et de test
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data[1:, [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


# Préparation des données en séquences
seq_length = 10  # Longueur de la séquence
X_train_seq = [trainset[i:i+seq_length, [6, 7, 8]] for i in range(len(trainset) - seq_length)]
Y_train_seq = [trainset[i+seq_length, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] for i in range(len(trainset) - seq_length)]
X_test_seq = [testset[i:i+seq_length, [6, 7, 8]] for i in range(len(testset) - seq_length)]
Y_test_seq = [testset[i+seq_length, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] for i in range(len(testset) - seq_length)]

X_train_seq = np.array(X_train_seq)
Y_train_seq = np.array(Y_train_seq)
X_test_seq = np.array(X_test_seq)
Y_test_seq = np.array(Y_test_seq)

print("X train seq shape : ", np.array(X_train_seq).shape)

# Création du modèle RNN avec tf.keras.Model
# input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))  # Entrée : x, y, z
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(seq_length, 3))  # Entrée : séquence de x, y, z
rnn_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(input_layer)  # Couche SimpleRNN
hidden_layer2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(rnn_layer)  # Couche intermédiaire
hidden_layer3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(hidden_layer2)  # Couche intermédiaire
hidden_layer4 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(hidden_layer3)  # Couche intermédiaire
hidden_layer5 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(hidden_layer4)  # Couche intermédiaire
hidden_layer6 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(hidden_layer5)  # Couche intermédiaire
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6)(hidden_layer6)  # 6 sorties pour les variables d'actionnement



model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

# Compilation du modèle
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Entraînement du modèle
History = model.fit(X_train_seq, Y_train_seq, validation_data=(X_test_seq, Y_test_seq), epochs=100, batch_size=512, verbose=2)
# History = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=500, batch_size=1024, verbose=2)

# Évaluation du modèle sur les données de test
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_seq, Y_test_seq, verbose=0)
# loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test accuracy:", accuracy)
print("Test loss:", loss)
```

Comment: Have you tried different combinations of layers, e.g. not 6x256?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jeppe yes i’ve tried lots of different combination. From one LSTM layer with 10 neurons to 10 LSTM layers with 512 neurons. I also changed batch size and epochs but the results is still the same